# Build error at sax.js

Tags: cordova, sax

I am building an App in cordova from commandline. But I have the following error. Can someone help me to resolve. I searced all over but, I couldnt find.[image]

My Environment Variables
%ANT_HOME% :
C:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3
%JAVA_HOME% :
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
PATH :
C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm;
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools;
%ANT_HOME%\bin;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
C:\apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;

Comment: Before doing a `build`, new need to create a `project`? Have you created a `project`?

Comment: Yes. I created a project, added android platform, and added plugins. I was unable to build and run

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for trouble guys,

I don't understand why but my current project has some problem. When I create another project and run. That is working fine. If anyone could find the problem please reply. For now I am recreating project.

Thank you for help